# Is it possible to create a standalone file to import a python library created with pybind?

Tags: python-2.7, pybind11, openimageio

I hope I'm clear in my question, if not please tell me.

I am using [OpenImageIO](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio)'s python bindings (pybind11) for some scripts that will run on hundreds of computers. Unfortunately it took me a lot of time to install OpenImageIO and make it work with my Python2 installation. I'd like to know if there's a way to create a file/folder that I could send to other computers so they can install the Python module simply with "pip install file/folder".

Thanks ofr your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the scripts on a compute cluster with a **shared filesystem?**  If so, then there's no need to create separate installations of python for each machine.  The simplest solution is to create ONE python environment in a location that is accessible by all of your machines.  An easy way to create a Python environment in a non-system location is to use [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).  Install it to a shared (network) location, and create an environment for all of your machines to use.

If your machines do NOT have a shared file system, then you'll need to somehow reproduce the environment on all of them independently.  In this case, there's no simple way to do that with `pip`.**

But if you can use `conda` instead, then there's a very straightforward solution.  First, install everything you need into a single conda environment.  Then you have a choice: You can export the list of conda packages, or simply copy the entire conda environment directory to the other machines.

OpenImageIO is available from the `conda-forge` channel, a community-developed repository of conda packages.  The name of the package is `py-openimageio`.  They have stopped updating the python-2.7 version, but the old versions are still available.

Here's how to do it.

1. Install [Miniconda-2.7](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

2. Create a new environment with python 2.7, OpenImageIO, and any other packages you need:

```
conda create -n jao-stuff -c conda-forge py-openimageio python=2.7
conda activate jao-stuff
python -c "import OpenImageIO; print('It works!')"
```

3. Do ONE of the following:

   a. Export the list of packages in your environment:

   ```
   conda env export -n jao-stuff -f jao-stuff-packages.yaml
   ```

   Then, on the other machines, install Miniconda, then create the environments using the package list from the previous step:

   ```
   conda create -n jao-stuff --file jao-stuff-packages.yaml
   ```

   **OR**

   b. Just copy all of the files in the environment to the other machines, and run them directly. Conda environments are self-contained (except for a few low-level system libraries), so you can usually just copy the whole thing to another machine and run it without any further install step.

   ```
   tar czf jao-stuff.tar.gz $(conda info --prefix)/envs/jao-stuff
   ```

   On the other machine, unpack the tarball anywhere and just run the `python` executable it contains:

   ```
   tar xzf jao-stuff.tar.gz
   jao-stuff/bin/python -c "import OpenImageIO; print('It works!')"
   ```

---

**That's because OpenImageIO is a C++ project, with several C++ dependencies, and they don't provide binaries in the `wheel` format.  I don't blame them -- pip is not well suited to this use-case, even with wheels.  Conda, on the other hand, was designed for exactly this use-case, and works perfectly for it.